# Can you use a number range in an if statement?

Tags: c++

I am working on a Codecademy project, and can't really find a solution to my question.

Given `weight` and `planet-number` as input, the goal of the exercise is to use a switch statement to return the `converted-weight` that you need to reach depending on the `planet-number` you want to go.

After calculating the `converted-weight`, I want to print some conditional message based on whether the `planet-number` is within in a valid range. I am facing difficulty in comparing `planet-number` for a valid range (e.g., `0-6` in this case). Here is my code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  double weight;
  int planet;
  double planetw;

  std::cout << "What is your Earth weight?\n";
  std::cin >> weight;

  std::cout << "What Planet number would you like to fight on? \n";
  std::cin >> planet;

switch (planet) {
case 1:
  planetw = weight * 0.38;
  break;
case 2:
  planetw = weight * 0.91;
  break;
case 3:
  planetw = weight * 0.38;
  break;
case 4:
  planetw = weight * 2.34;
  break;
case 5:
  planetw = weight * 1.06;
  break;
case 6:
  planetw = weight * 0.92;
  break;
case 7:
  planetw = weight * 1.19;
  break;
default:
  std::cout << "That is not a planet option\n";
  break;

}
 
if (planet) != range (0,6) {
  std::cout << "Pick a valid planet number next time.\n";
} else {
 std::cout << "Your traget weight to fight there is " << weight << " .\n";
}
}
```

Comment: This is where lookup tables are super handy: `std::map<int, double>` could store your various conversions.

Comment: Your range says `(0,6)`, but the switch cases are `1 .. 7`. I assume they're supposed to be the same?

Comment: Tip: Write functions to do these calculations. Don't just slam everything into `main()`.

Comment: Hint: `if (planet >= MIN && planet <= MAX)`

Comment: Typo in output, you compute `planetw`, but print `weight`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already handling the desired range of values in the `switch` cases, you can just utilize the `default` case that already exists, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  double weight;
  int planet;
  double planetw;

  std::cout << "What is your Earth weight?\n";
  std::cin >> weight;

  std::cout << "What Planet number would you like to fight on? \n";
  std::cin >> planet;

  switch (planet) {
  case 1:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 2:
    planetw = weight * 0.91;
    break;
  case 3:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 4:
    planetw = weight * 2.34;
    break;
  case 5:
    planetw = weight * 1.06;
    break;
  case 6:
    planetw = weight * 0.92;
    break;
  case 7:
    planetw = weight * 1.19;
    break;
  default:
    std::cout << "That is not a planet option\n";
    std::cout << "Pick a valid planet number next time.\n";
    return 0;
  }
 
  std::cout << "Your target weight to fight there is " << planetw << " .\n";

  return 0;
}
```

But, to answer your question, you can do a range check like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  double weight;
  int planet;
  double planetw;

  std::cout << "What is your Earth weight?\n";
  std::cin >> weight;

  std::cout << "What Planet number would you like to fight on? \n";
  std::cin >> planet;

  switch (planet) {
  case 1:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 2:
    planetw = weight * 0.91;
    break;
  case 3:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 4:
    planetw = weight * 2.34;
    break;
  case 5:
    planetw = weight * 1.06;
    break;
  case 6:
    planetw = weight * 0.92;
    break;
  case 7:
    planetw = weight * 1.19;
    break;
  default:
    std::cout << "That is not a planet option\n";
    break;
  }
 
  if (planet < 1 || planet > 7) {
    std::cout << "Pick a valid planet number next time.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Your target weight to fight there is " << planetw << " .\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you really want to use actual syntax like `if (planet != range(....))` then that is certainly doable, but it takes a bit more work to setup. You can do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct sRange
{
  int minValue;
  int maxValue;

  bool operator==(int value) const {
    return (value >= minValue && value <= maxValue);
  }

  bool operator!=(int value) const {
    return (value < minValue || value > maxValue);
  }
};

bool operator==(int value, const sRange &rhs) {
    return rhs == value;
}

bool operator!=(int value, const sRange &rhs) {
    return rhs != value;
}

sRange range(int minValue, int maxValue) {
    return sRange{minValue, maxValue};
}

int main() {

  double weight;
  int planet;
  double planetw;

  std::cout << "What is your Earth weight?\n";
  std::cin >> weight;

  std::cout << "What Planet number would you like to fight on? \n";
  std::cin >> planet;

  switch (planet) {
  case 1:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 2:
    planetw = weight * 0.91;
    break;
  case 3:
    planetw = weight * 0.38;
    break;
  case 4:
    planetw = weight * 2.34;
    break;
  case 5:
    planetw = weight * 1.06;
    break;
  case 6:
    planetw = weight * 0.92;
    break;
  case 7:
    planetw = weight * 1.19;
    break;
  default:
    std::cout << "That is not a planet option\n";
    break;
  }
 
  if (planet != range(1, 7)) { // or: if (range(1, 7) != planet)
    std::cout << "Pick a valid planet number next time.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Your target weight to fight there is " << planetw << " .\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go over so many options, while still answering my question! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Because you ask about range in `if` statement, so I answer your question without using `switch` statement.

You can do this

```cpp
if (planet > 7 || planet < 1) {
    std::cout << "That is not a planet option\n";
    std::cout << "Pick a valid planet number next time.\n";
}
else {
    double ratio[7] = {0.38, 0.91, 0.38, 2.34, 1.06, 0.92, 1.19};
    planetw = weight * ratio[planet-1];
    std::cout << "Your target weight to fight there is " << planetw << " .\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it as two conditions that would implement your range logic:

```c
if (planet > 7 || planet < 1) {
}
else {}
```

NB: you start at index 1 so your range is 1 to 7 included

These instructions translate sometimes in assembly code jg (jump if greater) and jl (jump if lower), but one trick used by compiler that works for unsigned integers is to substract the lower end and then just check if its lower or equal to the maximum bound.

```c
int tmp = planet - 1;
if (tmp > 6) { ... must be a valid planet message... }
```